Solution to Partial Differential Equation from Fourier Analysis
I am self-studying a Fourier Analysis course and I came across a very simple Partial Differential Equation, however I don't have much experience with PDEs and I was wondering how one would come to the solution?
The PDE in question is: $$\frac{\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y}=0$$
I know the general solution is $$F(x)+G(y)$$ for some functions $G$ and $F$, but I was wondering how you would derive the solution via double integration?

What do you mean by "via double integration"? If $\partial^2 f / \partial x , \partial y = 0$, then $g = \partial f/\partial y$ satisfies $\partial g / \partial x = 0$, which implies that $g$ is a constant with respect to $x$. However, this constant may still depend on $y$, which gives $g = \partial f / \partial y = c(y)$. Integrating this with respect to $y$, you obtain some new function $G(y) = \int c(y) , dy$ plus a constant, which (the constant) may depend on $x$. Now call this constant $F(x)$ and you're done.
